# How to develop performance benchmark program

Tags: performance, benchmarking

Probably everybody heard about different software used to measure performance of the hardware it is running on. I mean stuff like Windows Experience Rating, PCMark, Futuremark and so on. They are measuring different aspects of computer performance: CPU and GPU speed, memory access time, disk access time, and so on.

Could anybody explain how to develop such program, so it's result would be reliable? CPU, memory and disk access speed are of most importance for me, GPU and other stuff is not necessary. I suppose, there could be plenty of caveats there, like multi-core CPU, or CPU with dynamic frequency. Or different read and write speed in different sectors of HDD. Or something else.

I'd appreciate information about different aspects, not necessarily about all of what I mentioned, though it would be great.

P.S. I'm interested mostly in Windows environment, if it matters. But probably not.

Comment: This question is very broad. Here on StackOverflow you should ask about specific things, not about everything in general.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo, if I'll reformulate it as 'How to develop CPU benchmark under Windows 7', will it still be too broad?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/ has good reviews on hardware performance.

This is more of a programming forum (but it seems you know that because of your rating). https://superuser.com/ might appeal more to Windows performance questions.

As for your question, benchmarking is just timing how long it takes to do X operation or how many X operations can be done in X amount of time.

For benchmarking code, you would set a timestamp at the top of the code script and another timestamp at the bottom and compare the two. The difference (milliseconds usually) will be how fast your script is. Optimizing the code will reduce the difference (obviously).

The same goes with hardware usually. Better firmware or divers can make some difference. Upgrade your hardware if you feel that it is inadequate.

It's easy to see if you need more RAM, just see how much is being used, if it's 75%, then get more. RAM speed is also important. DDR3 1200-1600 is usually plenty.

In this day and age computers are so powerful that most people don't need an upgrade if you've bought a new computer within the past few years. Just keep junk programs off of it and run something like ccleaner regularly.

edit: As for how to develop a CPU benchmark: pick a formula or a operation which takes a long time, like calculating PI to X places then record how long it takes to do that. Then again, you also have to take into account the # of cores and other features which your benchmarking program might not be taking advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing a simple CPU benchmark to measure which fan position is more effective :)

My fist attempt is just to maximise CPU usage with simple arithmetic (counter++), while plotting current CPU speed, temperature and counter increments per second, but that is probably too simple.

One thing to keep in mind is that CPU's have different sections for floating point calculation and other stuff, some(all?) do it even in parallel, so you might want to consider that while generating load.

Also, probably you should account for physical/logical cores and do stuff multi-threaded.

App should warn the user if there is a lot of background CPU usage, that results are probably not OK.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar myself for my role at work.  I have a few tests for CPU Integer performance, one of which is a Mersenne Prime search.  This can double up as a load/stability test for the CPU.  The legendary stability testing software Prime95 was using Mersenne prime searches.

I found this Microsoft samples site to be incredibly helpful.  I modified this Mersenne Prime search for my needs, but it works out of the box:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BigInteger-Multitasking-eb319df1

When testing a CPU you also want to test floating point operations, haven't yet found anything useful on those, but will update this post if I do.

There was also a helpful comment on a similar question about testing RAM here:

[Benchmarking RAM performance - UWP and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763841/benchmarking-ram-performance-uwp-and-c-sharp)