# Benchmarking RAM performance - UWP and C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, benchmarking, ram, uwp

I'm developing a benchmarking application using Universal Windows Platform that evaluates CPU and RAM performance of a Windows 10 system.

Although I found different algorithms to benchmark a CPU, I still didn't found any solid algorithm or solution to evaluate the write and read speeds of memory.

How can I achieve this in C#?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Honestly I don't think its possible. RAM benchmarks usually run off of dedicated OS's (like in-memory Linux) and run read/write patterns (look up memtest). C# doesn't give you that kind of control over RAM, this is something you have to do a little lower level. You could probably write something in c++ and p/invoke it from c#.

Comment: @RonBeyer I see your point. After a bit of research on p/invoke that you suggested, calling C++ functions from a DLL seems to be a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why this would not be possible from managed code. Array access code turns into normal x86 memory instructions. It's a thin abstraction. In particular I don't see why you would need a customized OS.

You should be able to test sequential memory speed by performing memcpy on big arrays. They must be bigger than the last level cache size.

You can test random access by randomly indexing into a big array. The index calculation must be cheap, unpredictable and there must be a dependency chain that serializes the memory instructions so that the CPU cannot parallelize them.

> Honestly I don't think its possible. RAM benchmarks usually run off of dedicated OS's

RAM testing is different from RAM benchmarking.

> C# doesn't give you that kind of control over RAM

Of course, just new up a big array and access it. Also, understand the overheads that are present. The only overhead is a range check.

The GC has no impact during the benchmark. It might be triggered by an allocation.

Comment: Thank you for your time. So it can be done in C# but will results be as reliable as in C++, given the major language abstraction?

Comment: The abstraction cost is tiny. Try iterating over an array using a for loop and inspect the x86 code that was generated. There's not much there... If you want to test sequential speed you probably should access every 64th bytes. Touch each cache line once. 90% of the time this code will wait for memory.